# how can i extract the credentials from authorization header in Node js

Tags: node.js, angular

Angular

auth.service.ts

```
login(mobileNumber: number, password: string) {
    console.log(mobileNumber,password);
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json','Authorization': 'Basic '+window.btoa(mobileNumber + ':' + password) });
    let options = { headers: headers };
    return this.http.post<>("http://localhost:3000/api/user/login",{}, options)
     }
```

Node js

User.js

```
router.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {
let user = basicAuth(req);
 console.log("mobile number is ",user.name);
});
```

**Error Message :
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined**

Comment: Can you share the the implementation of the `basicAuth` function?

Comment: Hi Mureinik ,
I have imported the basic-auth function like below
const basicAuth = require('basic-auth');